# Time lapse screen recording for iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, screen-recording

How can I take a time lapse screen recording on iOS? I want to make a video that shows the behaviour of an app over a long period of time (1-3 hours).

I know I can just make a screen recording of the whole thing, but that would take a lot of storage space in the meantime and take a lot of time in post processing to speed up the video.

Is there an app that can do time lapse screen recording? Is it even possible for an app to have permission to do this?